# AngularJS-Toaster how to kill a toaster

Tags: angularjs, message

How to stop a AngularJS-Toaster  before starting the other one like i want to stop the

```
toaster.pop('wait', "Email verification", 'Email is Sending');
```

and want to show the new toaster for success like

```
toaster.pop('success', "Email verification", "Your mail has been sent successfully. Please check your email id for the verification link.");
```

can anyone one tell me how to kill a toaster????

Answer (score 5):

Hi i found its so simple just use

**toaster.clear();**

method to kill a toaster.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the source code of that directive that there is a method called removeToast. You can pass a toast id and it will remove the toast. Did you try that one?

```
scope.removeToast = function (id) {
      var i, len, toast;
      for (i = 0, len = scope.toasters.length; i < len; i++) {
          if (scope.toasters[i].id === id) {
              removeToast(i);
              break;
          }
      }
  };
```

[Source: AngularJS-Toaster @ Github](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster/blob/master/toaster.js#L238)

Comment: how to get the id of toast??